# Date function in mysql result different why?

Tags: mysql, date

**I have  two queries.**

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 b 
WHERE  b.registerDate BETWEEN '2015-03-01' AND '2015-03-31'


SELECT * FROM table1 b 
WHERE  date(registerDate) between 2015-03-01 and '2015-03-31'
```

both queries result is different why??

Comment: You have not added the single quote to the date in second query. Here 2015-03-01

Comment: it's ok but still different result .

Comment: Someone can tell about the internal working of date() function except that it extract date part only.?

Comment: Read through.... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-date.html

Comment: very helpful link ... Thanks James

Answer (score 0):

When i used timestamp in fisrt query I get same result from both the queries .
You can find the query below.

I think it is correct answer.

SELECT * FROM table1 b WHERE b.registerDate BETWEEN '2015-03-01' AND '2015-03-31 23:59:59'

SELECT * FROM table1 b WHERE date(registerDate) between '2015-03-01' and '2015-03-31'

Please suggest that it is right or wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

When you say `'2015-03-01'`  its `'2015-03-01 00:00:00'`

when you say `date(registerDate)` it ignores the  time part  and return  only the date  part.

```
b.registerDate BETWEEN '2015-03-01' AND '2015-03-31'
```

means `registerDate with time`  between `'2015-03-01  00:00:00'` AND `'2015-03-31  00:00:00'`

```
date(registerDate) between 2015-03-01 and '2015-03-31'
```

means `registerDate with  out time  part(i.e date 00:00:00)`  between `'2015-03-01  00:00:00'` AND `'2015-03-31  00:00:00'`

Its bad  idea to compare a `data` filed to `string` field.
You can use `Date` literal to convert string to `date`.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 b 
WHERE date(b.registerDate) BETWEEN Date'2015-03-01' AND Date'2015-03-31'
```